# Objects Memory Usage in Android

Tags: android, object, memory

I'm doing preloading for Activities. I loaded root views of Activities by inflate the Layout files during apps launching. I am wondering the RAM consumption for those View objects. Is there any way to estimate their memory usage?

I am using Debug.MemInfo to show some memory information before and after loading views. Comparing the totalPrivateDirty showed the memory usage of each view is just several KBs. I hope to find another way to estimated their memory usage to confirm they were correct.

Thank you.

Methods for estimating or measuring memory usage of View objects in Android